# Stripe: Can you save cards to a customer if you use Stripe's new hosted Checkout?

Tags: stripe-payments

Right now with my Stripe implementation using Stripe Elements, when a customer enters their card details and it's saved to the Stripe customerr so that they can seamlessly come back next time to purchase by selecting their card(s) by a dropdown showing the last 4 digits.
I looked at Stripe's new-ish Checkout option where the check is done on their site (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/) , am I able to have saved cards for a user?  All I could find was this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/updating but this looks like it could only be applied to actual subscriptions and not to just have a list of saved cards for a user so they can select which to make a purchase from next time.  Anyone know for sure?

Comment: Yes you can. You can use Checkout in Setup Mode where customer parameter 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-mode

Comment: thanks @wsw .  That seems to be outside of a purchase flow though where a user can add a card.  I tried adding it to a purchase with line_items and it threw an error:` `You can not pass line_items in setup mode.`.  I am curious if there's a way to automatically save the card as part of the purchase flow -- not have a separate flow for saving cards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

When making a payment on Stripe Checkout, the user has the option to save their payment details.

This feature is enabled for you by default unless you disable "Link with Stripe" in your Checkout Settings.